# Label in WPF application not updating

Tags: wpf, label

I have the following code:

```
label1.content = "Start";
bool a = executeLongTask();
label1.content = "Done";
```

For some reason the label only gets updated to "Done" after the executeLongTask() method is completed. It completely skips displaying the "Start" message.

Why is the label not being set to "Start" when the application is running and how would I make it update to "Start" first without using multiple threads?

The executeLongTask() method by the way calls a PowerShell script and awaits it output before proceeding onto label1.content = "Done";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For some reason the label only gets updated to "Done" after the executeLongTask() method is completed. It completely skips displaying the "Start" message.

That's because the UI thread needs to return to its main loop in order to process `WM_PAINT` updates. When you set the label the first time, WPF makes a note that it should redraw the label when it returns to the message processing loop. Then the UI is kept busy in the `executeLongTask` method, and then the label is set the second time, and WPF again makes a note that it should redraw the label. When you return control to the UI message loop, it finally gets a chance to actually *do* the redraw and update what you see on the screen.

> how would I make it update to "Start" first without using multiple threads?

The easiest solution *is* to use multiple threads. Example:

```
label1.content = "Start";
bool a = await Task.Run(() => executeLongTask());
label1.content = "Done";
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite `executeLongTask` to act asynchronously, and then you wouldn't need a separate thread:

```
label1.content = "Start";
bool a = await executeLongTaskAsync();
label1.content = "Done";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed and informative post. I didn't realize that WPF takes a note of the label to be updated and then actually sets it when it comes back from the method. Thus I was confused as to why it can't just set the first label, perform the long execution, and then set the last label. Thank you again, I think I will go with the first solution you provided.

Answer (score 1):

The text will only update after the function returns. If you want it to update while `executeLongTask()` is running you need to use the [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) pattern. The will let you return control until the long task completes.

Answer (score 1):

Have simple solution see below:

Solution 1:

`label1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=> { label1.content = "Message"; }), System.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);`

Solution 2:
1.Add "System.Windows.Forms" namespace in reference section
2.Write as below:

`label1.content = "Message"; System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();`